# Get the first match with re.findall without access to any Python code

Tags: python, regex

I am trying in Python 3.7 to recognize patterns in pdf documents by extracting the elements with regular expressions. The problem I have is related to the fact that I need only the first match of the regular expression. However when I occupy my regex it finds both.

```
"FECHA DE EMISION ","26/03/2021 "
"Comuna: ","Valparaiso "
"FECHA DE EMISION ","26/03/2021 "
```

The regex I am using is:

```
(FECHA\sDE\sEMISION.*)
```

The result I need is just the first match of the regex to get:

> **"FECHA DE EMISION ","26/03/2021 "**

It is important to note that the two matches they make are the same content.

I also tried to use the Contents statement `\g<1>` capture group 1, but it didn't work for me. I think it has to do with that I am not using lazy greedy.

**It is important to note that I cannot solve it directly with Python or with functionalities of it.** I specifically use `re.findall`, but I can't add any other additional functionality, that's why I need an expression that resolves to bring me only the first match.

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: I forgot to mention that the order may be different.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It does not work. I am using regex101.com with python 2.7

Comment: That is why. Use it in Python 3.x, some latest versions. Or, use a less fine `^[\s\S]*?(FECHA\sDE\sEMISION.*)`

Comment: I understand, however is there a way to limit me to match only once? I need him to bring me only the first from that match.

Comment: Disable `m` modifier and the regex above works. Or, if you need a regex to absolutely work at regex101.com, it is `\A[\s\S]*?(FECHA\sDE\sEMISION.*)`. But do you really need a regex to work in a regex tester or in Python? What is your code? What input goes to what method? If the text is read line by line, this regex won't work in the end, however cool it looks in an online tool.

Comment: I mean I use regex101 to test, but I really need it to work in python 3.7. I specifically use re.findall. But I can't add any other additional functionality, that's why I need an expression that resolves to bring me only the first match.

Comment: re.search() will always return the first match. See this: https://www.bing.com/search?q=python+re+mathc+first+instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you could use PCRE/Onigmo/Boost regex engine or PyPi `regex` module**, you could get the match value directly using

```
\A[\s\S]*?\K"FECHA\sDE\sEMISION.*
```

where `\K` makes the regex engine "forget" the text matched so far. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hvQkXu/2).

**Since you are bound to use a pattern for `re.findall`**, you can use

```py
\A[\s\S]*?("FECHA\sDE\sEMISION.*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hvQkXu/1).

*Details*:

- `\A` - unambiguous start of string
- `[\s\S]*?` - any zero or more chars, as few as possible
- `("FECHA\sDE\sEMISION.*)` - Capturing group 1: `"FECHA DE EMISION` with any whitespace between the words and then the rest of the line.

Comment: In this case, what would happen if I have text before the result?

Comment: @NegalWoods It will get consumed and discarded from the return value since `re.findall` only returns the captured substring.

Comment: Yeah! it's work. I solved with your help!